# View external library source code added by nuget in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, resharper

I use resharper and have configured symbol source providers as describe http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio

And now I can debug code (view it source on debugging), but i cannot just view it (without starting of debugging).

For example I can view String class source code by using "go to definition". But when i try use it for nuget libraries I cannot see source code. I see only member declaration (interface) That is gotten by "Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler" (but still i can see that full source code on debugging).

Comment: Check `ReSharper - Options - Tools - External Sources`. You probably need to select `Navigation to Sources` option.